# How to perform Undo operations on drawing lines in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

I have to perform undo functionality in the view so that i get back previous drawing line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implemement undo featuers in painting application in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872579/how-to-implemement-undo-featuers-in-painting-application-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Array variable as a class variable an then try calling in validate.
It will work

EX:

```
class Xyz extends View{
    ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();
    .....
}
```