# How to implemement undo features in painting application in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, undo-redo

i want to do undo features in in my application.. for this i searched i net found that take arraylist of x,y points which i have done below code i am unable for undo the drawings ??

```
public Drawview(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
            super(context);


            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 1200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
           // mainbitmap.add(mBitmap);
            //System.out.println("**mBitmapPaint***"+mBitmapPaint);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);



        }

       @Override
       protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
           super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
       }

        @Override 
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            System.out.println("***Drawinglines****"+Drawinglines);

                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);



        }


        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {


            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        ///    path.
            //graphics.add(mPath);
            mPath.reset();
        }

        // events when touching the screen
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

             event.getAction();
            int eventaction = event.getAction(); 

            int X = (int)event.getX(); 
            int Y = (int)event.getY(); 

            switch (eventaction ) { 

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

            {
                touch_start(X, Y);
                }
                 invalidate(); 
                 break; 


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  

                System.out.println("***ACTION_MOVE**************"+X+"************"+Y);
                if((Drawinglines.equals("Pen"))||(Drawinglines.equals("Erase")))
                {
                  touch_move(X, Y);
                  temp_point.add(new Point(X,Y));

                }
                invalidate(); 
                break; 

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                main_Points.add(temp_point);
                temp_point = null;

                 touch_up();  

                 invalidate(); 
                 break; 
            } 

            return true; 

        }




        public void undopath()
        {   
              main_Points.remove(main_Points.size()-1);
             invalidate();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(v ==  Undo)
        {    
            Drawview abc=new Drawview();
             abc.undopath();
        }
```

But undo undo functionality is not working.

Comment: And what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: My problem is According to the code i have made Arraylist of x,y  points after deleting after element from arraylist how i get  after this line of main_Points.remove(main_Points.size()-1);how get previous drawings lines

Comment: Yeah, but where is your undo/redo-logic that you have tried so far? You say: "Undo is not working", but I do not see the undo-code that you say is not working.

Comment: start reading about the Command design pattern

Comment: So, if your problem is that you don't know how to implement undo/redo, then you should search SO first for "undo redo". And never post "it is urgent, plz". I bet if I wouldn't have edited your post, you would have received downvotes, because we are not a side where prioritizing is free, and we are doing voluntary jobs here.

Comment: Also: Don't flood SO with dupes.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Slate mSlate;
private TiledBitmapCanvas mTiledCanvas;

 public void clickUndo(View unused) {

        mSlate.undo();
    }


public void undo() {
        if (mTiledCanvas == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "undo before mTiledCanvas inited");
        }
        mTiledCanvas.step(-1);

        invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try, but i think use two canvas and bitmaps is helpful, on draw the current state, one is still former state, only need to restore the former one. But it only can restore on step.

Comment: Hi, this is more of a comment than an answer.... can you update it with some code that demonstrates that you're correct?

Answer (score 0):

here some code:
create:

```
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Bitmap mBitmap;

private Canvas mRestoreCanvas;
private Bitmap mRestoreBitmap;
```

init:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mPictureWidth = w;
    mPictureHeight = h;

    Loge.i("mPictureWidth = " + mPictureWidth + " mPictureHeight = "
            + mPictureHeight);
    if (mCanvas == null && mBitmap == null && mPictureWidth > 0
            && mPictureHeight > 0) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPictureWidth, mPictureHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mCanvas.save();

        mRestoreBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPictureWidth, mPictureHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mRestoreCanvas = new Canvas(mRestoreBitmap);
        mRestoreCanvas.save();
    }
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}
```

onDraw:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mPattern == DRAW_LINE) {
        mCanvas.restore();
        mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        mCanvas.save();
    }
    mCanvas.save();
    if (mBitmap != null)
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

onTouchEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        mRestoreCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
    }

    if (mPattern == DRAW_LINE) {
        return drawLines(event);
    } else if (mPattern == DRAW_PATTERN) {
        return drawPattern(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Undo:

```
public void dust() {
    path.reset();
    mBitmap.recycle();
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPictureWidth, mPictureHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);

    mCanvas.drawBitmap(mRestoreBitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);

    invalidate();
}
```

Tested OK;

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have used a kind of trick to remove the black line.In my erase button, I have set the color to white, instead of using XferMode..

```
  if(erase){
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }
```